# Mobile Charge effects on Band Diagrams

Tags: electronic-band-theory

Hi I have a question which I think is related more to definitions than anything else. 
Consider a band diagram.  PN junction, heterostructure, whatever it might be. It's a very useful tool to determine where there is field, where there is space charge by slopes, band bending etc.

However, as I recall, the strictest definition is that this is the potential an electron sees due to the hybridization of the atomic lattice states.  Any charges, i.e. defect/traps, surfaces, polarization charges, etc. are all fixed.  Does this mean that mobile charge cannot contribute to the band diagram in the strictest definition?

For instance, the Kirk effect in HBT/BJTs essentially "undoes" some of the reverse bias band bending when a large electron current is passing through such that there is a condition J less than qns for the band diagram to be plausible.  OR what about strongly correlated systems, like perovskites, where alot of the physics is due to electron electron interactions, which is NOT including in BDs? Alot of work goes into Mott-Hubbard transistions, which if I recall correctly cannot be inferred from BDs.

So are band diagrams technically only the potential seen in a fictional "1 electron" system, which is a valid approximation assuming an electron gas?  Or could one in principle, create BD's which do involve mobile carrier potential (Assuming one could solve those difficult Hamiltonians!)

Thanks! I'd love to hear some opinions!

Comment: So you would assert that a metal, with free carriers, does not have a band diagram to explain the electronic states?

Comment: Not necessarily. Although for metals (at least when contacted to semiconductors), you just assume filled states below Ef as there is no bandgap, at least for gamma point BDs which I am talking about.  But even then, metals are still an "electron gas" assuming the drude model.  But lets say we plot a BD for metals, under a huge voltage, or will some space charge stuck inside, would the free carrier screening completely flatten the band again?

Comment: A further point to consider is that the electronic band structured can be measured experimentally, and compare well with calculations. The calculations usually have to include various corrections beyond the naive single electron approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic orbitals are a solution for an electron configuration around an isolated atom.  Outer orbitals turn into bands when many atoms are close together in a solid (or liquid, for that matter).
An electron in a metal is in a part-filled band, and while it is free to wander inside the conductor, it is not 'free'; if it were, cathodes in vacuum tubes
wouldn't require heaters.

As to defects and mismatched atoms, the knowledge we have of bands is from calculations on repetitive structures (like a crystal lattice); defects and impurities
are local, and bands are global (apply to a large lattice) not
local.   The local electronic state near an impurity isn't part of the band picture.   For working semiconductors, the impurities are very few and
far between, so they don't change the bands much...

In perovskite superconductors, the actual electron collective couplings
are weak (interesting, but modest temperature is all it takes to scramble
their effects).  Similarly, ferromagnetism is a collective electron
effect that is too subtle to show up in a band diagram.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't really answer my question.  Lets say you have a large voltage applied across say a band diagram, the fields start to slope.  But at a certain point, does the charge of the mobile current $J=qnv$ become so large that it counteracts the bias?  Does mobile charge travelling as current contribute to a BD or not?  From your answer based on atomic orbitals, I would guess your answer is no.

Comment: It is customary to show a band diagram for (for instance) a PN junction with the electric field (there's one built-in to each junction, because of thermal driven diffusion) causing a band bending.   This is to represent the energy diagram (band structure) as perturbed by the charges in the vicinity of the junction, and not so much the charge motion (current).   Fully reaching through the depletion region at a PN junction would have an effect, but that requires unrealistic currents (would melt the semiconductor).